# f2py: printing a function

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I try to build a very simple example of f2py program to print the result of a function. The program is build as follow:

1) a main program in which I call the function:

```
subroutine function_main
use parameters
implicit none
!-------------------------------------!
   integer, PARAMETER :: n = 2 ! dimension of the function ( = num. of variables)
  real*8, parameter :: a = 0.001d0 
!-------------------------------------!
   real*8, DIMENSION(n) :: x ! this is the vector 
   integer :: m

 m = n
! DECLARE THE variables !
 x(1) = 0.d0
 x(2) = 0.001d0  

print*, 'chi2(x,m)'
print*, chi2(x,m)

end subroutine function_main
```

2) a module in which I define the function:

```
MODULE parameters

 contains

real*8 function chi2(x,m)
implicit none
!-------------------------------------!
   integer, PARAMETER :: n = 2 ! dimension of the function ( = num. of variables)
   real*8, parameter :: a = 0.001d0 
!-------------------------------------!
    real*8, dimension(n) :: var
    real*8, DIMENSION(n) :: x ! defined in the main program
    integer :: m
   var(1)=x(1)
   var(2)=x(2)-asin(x(2))

 chi2 = 1.d0 + (var(2)-a)**2.d0

end function

end module parameters
```

I post it the modify version of the program as should be used with f2py ( http://websrv.cs.umt.edu/isis/index.php/F2py_example I follow this guide). I compile and launch the program with the following commands:

```
f2py -m function_main -h function_main.pyf function_module.f90    function_main.f90
```

and

```
f2py -c --fcompiler=gnu95 test_basic.pyf function_module.f90 function_main.f90
```

It create the following function_main.pyf file (I link the file [here](http://speedy.sh/x7HU8/function-main.pyf)), and I use the  Ipython script to launch it:

```
import function_main

def run():
 n = 2
 m = 2
 a = 0.001

 funtion_main.function_main()

if __name__=='__main__':    

    print function_main.chi2
```

I think that the only problem is in this script because I am able to create the 
function_main.so needed to launch the program via python. In fact the errors I receive is the follow:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'chi2'
```

Could someone help me? Thanks a lot !

Comment: `f2py` doesn't work with Fortran functions.  Try making it a subroutine.

Comment: @SethMMorton I have a subroutine... I don't understand the comment.

Comment: You have implented `chi2` as a function in Fortran. `f2py` cannot wrap this into something that is callable from python. Try re-implementing `chi2` as a subroutine with an output variable, because `f2py` can wrap that.